# Как вывести то что находится в бд

Tags: sqlite, aiogram

подскажите как вывести то что находится в бд.
А точнее мне надо чтобы бот выдавал данные пользователя который ввёл комманду

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["my"])
async def load_desc(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
async with state.proxy() as data:
    data["name","age","description"]
    await message.reply(f"{data['name']}\n{data['age']}\n{data['description']}")
```

Comment: data["name"] = message.from_user.first_name  Вообще можно так структуру message посмотреть: print(message.as_json())

Comment: Ты меня не правильно понял, если делать так как ты сказал он выдаёт имя пользователя. А мне надо чтобы он выдавал имя которое в базе данных

Comment: Ну так и ишите по id в базе данных: select ..... Какая она там у Вас - postgres, mysql, sqlite....